# how to set h20 partial_plot partial dependence plot figsize

Tags: python

After building random forest model with H20, I want to see the effect for a single feature so I used `model.partial_plot(data=valid, cols=['types'], plot=True, nbins=100,plot_stddev = False )`
But the plot size is very small, is there a way I could change the plot figsize and font size?

Comment: Both could be adjusted thru the use of `'figsize'` along with the `'fontsize'` param. Refer to my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the parameter `figsize=(10, 6)` (here this is 10 x 6 inches) or in a separate line of code `model.figure_.set_size_inches(10, 6)`.

- Reference for `'figsize'` parameter: [scikit-learn.org docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_partial_dependence_visualization_api.html?highlight=partial%20plot%20figsize#plotting-partial-dependence-of-the-two-models-together)

As for the font, there is a `fontsize` parameter which takes a value of `'small'`,`'medium'`, or `'large'`. It is set by `fontsize='large'`, for example.

- Reference for `'fontsize'` parameter (see accepted answer):
  [How to get the associated axis of a bar chart in python Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65211861/how-to-get-the-associated-axis-of-a-bar-chart-in-python-matplotlib/65212075#65212075)